# Calculation view for material to material transfer

Tags: sql, pivot, hana

I have a table Tab1 with two rows

```
+-------+----------+--------------+----------+--------+
| DOC#  | Material | Debit/Credit | Quantity | Amount |
+-------+----------+--------------+----------+--------+
| 12345 | A1       | Credit       |        5 |     50 |
| 12345 | B1       | Debit        |        5 |     50 |
+-------+----------+--------------+----------+--------+
```

**Desired Result**

```
+-------+---------------+-------------+----------+--------+
| DOC#  | From Material | To Material | Quantity | Amount |
+-------+---------------+-------------+----------+--------+
| 12345 | A1            | B1          |        5 |     50 |
+-------+---------------+-------------+----------+--------+
```

I am working on SAP HANA, writing a calculation view.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your description doesn't make sense, because the values within a column *all mean the same there*.  There is no "to material" in one row and "from material" in another, unless a column specifies which is which.

Comment: How can two rows in the same table have different columns? Do you mean that one column is null in the row?

Comment: This looks like a flawed design by the way if you consider from and to belonging together when they have the same document number and happen to have the same amount and quantity. You seem to expect to find multiple transactions in one document number and different transactions must not have the same amount and quantity. But what if they do?

Comment: So the table does not contain From Material and To Material, but a Debit/Credit column. Please change your description accordingly. And please paste the table as text instead of linking to an image. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: You need to do a [tag:pivot] operation. I guess the `credit` and `debit` values on the rows of your ledger govern `to` and `from`.

Comment: What is your DBMS? You should tag SQL questions always with the DBMS you are using in order to get appropriate answers.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation as follows:

```
Select doc#,
       Max(case when debit_credit = 'credit' then material end) as from_material, 
       Max(case when debit_credit = 'debit' then material end) as to_material, 
       Quantity, Amount
  From t
 Group by doc#, quantity, amount
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to aggregation is a self-join. I guess that is easy to understand for beginners. You join the credit rows to the debit rows, as if these were two different tables.

```
select
  doc_number, quantity, amount,
  debit.material as from_material,
  credit.material as to_material
from (select * from tab1 where credit_debit = 'Credit') as credit
join (select * from tab1 where credit_debit = 'Debit') as debit
  using (doc_number, quantity, amount)
order by doc_number, quantity, amount;
```

It may be that HANA lacks the `USING` clause. Then the query would become

```
select
  credit.doc_number, credit.quantity, credit.amount,
  debit.material as from_material,
  credit.material as to_material
from (select * from tab1 where credit_debit = 'Credit') as credit
join (select * from tab1 where credit_debit = 'Debit') as debit
  on  credit.doc_number  =  debit.doc_number
  and credit.quantity    =  debit.quantity
  and credit.amount      =  debit.amount
order by credit.doc_number, credit.quantity, credit.amount;
```

Comment: Which one would give me a better performance?

Comment: I don't know. If your table is not that big, it doesn't matter much anyhow. I like the aggregation approach much better, just thought I show the alternative. There is one difference though. My query only shows matches while Popeye's query also shows rows without a match (i.e. only debit or only credit exists). If you want to rstrict Popeye's query to matches, add `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2` or the like. Both queries may (or may not) benefit from an index on document number, quantity and amount by the way.